# insert text to sqlite where text have &quot;

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to read query string from URL and save them into a sqlite database
I face with these Error message:

```
PHP Warning:  SQLite3::exec(): near &quot;,&quot;: syntax error
```

But I don't the problems:

```
$Tel = $_REQUEST["from"];
$Content = $_REQUEST["text"];
echo $Tel = strip_tags($Tel);
echo $Content = strip_tags($Content);
   $sql =<<<EOF

      INSERT INTO foodordering(Fullname, Tel, RecievingTime, Content)
      VALUES ("Ehsan", $Tel, date('now'), $Content);

EOF;

   $ret = $db->exec($sql);
```

Comment: you need to secure your inputs, read more about prepared statements , or/and manually escape your inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [@HassanAhmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385470/insert-text-to-sqlite-where-text-have-quot/42398079#comment71919552_42385470), this is what happens when inputs are not properly handled; you're seeing the same issue as if someone was using [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3775731) against you. The quick fix is to wrap the fields in quotation marks:

```
VALUES ("Ehsan", "$Tel", date('now'), "$Content");
```

***What you should be doing is binding the parameters***:

```
$sql =<<<EOF

INSERT INTO foodordering(Fullname, Tel, RecievingTime, Content)
VALUES ("Ehsan", :tel, date('now'), :content);

EOF;

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':tel', $_REQUEST['from']);
$stmt->bindValue(':content', $_REQUEST['text']);

$ret = $stmt->execute();
```